# странная работа цикла

Tags: php

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($orders1 as $item) {
    $data['orders'][$i] = $item;
    if ($item['products_id']) {
        $tmp = explode(',', $item['products_id']);

        $j = 0;
        foreach ($tmp as $item1) {
            $data['orders'][$i]['products_id'][$j] = $item1;

            $this->session->set_userdata('tmp', $data['orders'][$i]['products_id'][$j]);
            $j++;
        }
    }

    $i++;
}
```

вот, что из себя представляет массив `$orders1`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 17
        [user_id] => 111
        [order_fio] => Fedorov Nikolay
        [order_date] => 2017-03-11 09:00:33
        [order_change_status] => 2017-03-11 09:00:33
        [order_status] => 0
        [order_adress] => Fedorov Nikolay,Fedorov Nikolay,Fedorov Nikolay
        [number] => 543
        [products_id] => 11,10
        [discount] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 18
        [user_id] => 111
        [order_fio] => Fedorov Nikolay
        [order_date] => 2017-03-11 09:01:13
        [order_change_status] => 2017-03-11 09:01:13
        [order_status] => 0
        [order_adress] => Fedorov Nikolay,Fedorov Nikolay,Fedorov Nikolay
        [number] => 423
        [products_id] => 11,10
        [discount] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 19
        [user_id] => 111
        [order_fio] => Fedorov Nikolay
        [order_date] => 2017-03-11 09:02:27
        [order_change_status] => 2017-03-11 09:02:27
        [order_status] => 0
        [order_adress] => Fedorov Nikolay,Fedorov Nikolay,Fedorov Nikolay
        [number] => 432
        [products_id] => 11,10
        [discount] => 0
    )
)
```

в `$this->session->set_userdata` выводится первая цифра из строки 11,10. Но я ведь строку разбил на массив из двух чисел. То есть, если я вывожу `$item1`, то выводится 11, а если `$data['orders'][$i]['products_id'][$j]`, то цифра 1. Хотя строкой выше я сделал их равными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно у Вас  `$data['orders'][$i]['products_id']` это строка  '11,10', `$data['orders'][$i]['products_id'][$j]`  - это первый элемент строки '1' который вы хотите приравнять строке.

```
    $i = 0;
foreach ($orders1 as $item) {
    $data['orders'][$i] = $item;
    if ($item['products_id']) {
        $tmp = explode(',', $item['products_id']); // результата [11, 10]

        $j = 0;
        foreach ($tmp as $item1) {
            $data['orders'][$i]['products_id'][$j] = $item1; // 1 = 11 - так не работает, если вы хотите сделать products_id то надо убрать  [$j], а  если хотите создать новый  массив айдишников, то надо записать $data['orders'][$i]['products_ids'][] =  !!!
            ...
        }
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Вообще подразумеваю, что вы ходите создать в каждом массиве свой массив айдишников.

```
foreach ($orders1 as $item) {
    $data['orders'][$i] = $item;
    if ($item['products_id']) {
        $tmp = explode(',', $item['products_id']);
        $j = 0;
        $data['orders'][$i]['products_ids'] = [];
        foreach ($tmp as $item1) {

            $data['orders'][$i]['products_ids'][] = $item1;


            //$this->session->set_userdata('tmp', $item1);
            $j++;
        }

    }

    $i++;
}
```

**Результат**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: понятно.. и точно, это ведь первый элемент строки я брал, благодарю